# The English term used for a complete and happy person

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an English word which describes a completed person who is ethicly mature.
A word with the same meaning or feeling as the Yiddish word *mensch*.

For example:

- How can we guide my son to become a ...
- Despite his struggles in    life he was a real ...

Comment: Which are you after "a complete and happy person" or "a completed person who is ethicly mature" or both? What's your definition of "complete" in this context?

Comment: You'll struggle to get a hypernym for all your attributes, as @KillingTime implies.

Comment: ***A fulfilled person*** - a person feeling happy because they are getting everything that they  want from life:

Comment: In Hinduism, Luck is considered to have three aspects - good health, long life and peace of mind.  With one missing, a man's life is nothing. Hence, the parents pray God that their children be blessed with luck having the elements of good health, long life and peace of mind. I am still not saying 'Luck/ Lucky' is the word that can meet the above. Just quoted an example. In Sanskrit, there is a verse, "Bhagyavantham Prasooyedha; Maa Shooram; Maa cha: Panditam" which means, a mother should give birth to a baby that is lucky, not scholarly, or  warrior-like.

Comment: @KillingTime a completed person who is ethicly mature would be great :-)

Comment: If I look up synonyms for [mensch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/mensch), I get [**stalwart**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stalwart). If that isn't sufficient, explain why not. Also, there might not be an English equivalent. Also note that an actual definition of [mensch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mensch) is "a person of integrity and honour." Your addition of "complete and happy" doesn't seem to apply. So, which is it? Or do you really want to combine the multiple meanings?

Comment: I think I've only heard "mensch" used sarcastically.

Comment: Calling someone a mensch is a simple but big compliment. Because it encompasses so much, it is hard to translate. Stalwart is close, but with warmth. A sport, for sure. A real grown-up, maybe.  Decent and mature. Neighborly. Talmudic aphorism: "Who is rich? One who is happy with his lot." That's a mensch. I've also heard "I don't need Prince Charming - just find me a mensch."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about **stand-up guy** (or politically-correct equivalent for *guy*)?

From M-W dictionary:

> [**stand-up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand-up): marked by a high degree of personal integrity of loyalty, e.g., a *stand-up* guy

From M-W thesaurus:

> [**stand-up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/stand-up): following the accepted rules of moral conduct, e.g., he's a real *stand-up* guy, he's willing to raise the child—by himself if necessary
>
> Synonyms for **stand-up**: decent, ethical, honest, honorable, just, noble, principled, respectable, righteous, upright, upstanding

Your examples:

> *How can we guide my son to become a **stand-up guy**?*
>
> *Despite his struggles in life, he was a real **stand-up guy**.*